Rejected ports within `DOCKER-USER` are still visible from nmap as "filtered"
by default Docker will adjust iptables according to containers bound to the host... but in my case I don't want to have all exposed to internet. What I'm doing is modifying the chain DOCKER-USER so it does not get overriden by Docker. Then I simulate a rejection so tools like nmap should not consider other ports as "filtered":
sudo iptables -F DOCKER-USER
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ens3 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i ens3 -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i ens3 -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

But it does not work at all, ports are still seen as "filtered" with nmap (using nmap -p- $(curl -s ifconfig.me)). Maybe it should be done outside DOCKER-USER but it's the only way to colocate with Docker peacefully.
Any help appreciated :)

Remember that iptables interprets rules in order, so if a matching ACCEPT rule is encountered before it reaches your REJECT rule, the packet will be accepted.
